# R data.table Conditional Sum: Cleaner way

Tags: r, data.table

*This of course is a very often encountered problem, so I have expected many questions here on SO regarding this. However, all the answers that I could find were very specific to the question and often encountered workarounds (you don't have to do this, **foobar** is much better in this scenario) or non data.table solutions. Perhaps this is because it should be a no-brainer with data.table*

I have a data.table which contains yearly data on `tentgelt` and `te_med`. For each year, I want to know the share of observations for which `tentgelt > te_med`. This is what I am doing:

```
# note that nAbove and nBelow do not add up to 1
nAbove <- wages[tentgelt > te_med, list(nAbove = .N), by=list(year)]
nBelow <- wages[tentgelt < te_med, list(nBelow = .N), by=list(year)]
nBelow[nAbove][, list(year, foo=nAbove/(nAbove+nBelow))]
```

which works but whenever I see other people's `data.table` code, it looks much clearer and easier than my workarounds. Is there a cleaner way to get the following type of output?

```
   year       foo
 1: 1993 0.2372093
 2: 1994 0.1567568
 3: 1995 0.8132530
 4: 1996 0.1235955
 5: 1997 0.1065574
 6: 1998 0.3070684
 7: 1999 0.1491974
```

Here's a sample of my data:

```
   year tentgelt    te_med
 1: 2010   120.95  53.64929
 2: 2010     9.99 116.72601
 3: 2010   113.52  53.07394
 4: 2010    10.27  38.45728
 5: 2010    48.58 124.65753
 6: 2010    96.38  86.99060
 7: 2010     3.46  65.75342
 8: 2010   107.52  91.87592
 9: 2010   107.52  42.92953
10: 2010     3.46  73.92328
11: 2010    96.38  85.23419
12: 2010     2.25  79.19995
13: 2010    42.32  35.75757
14: 2010     7.94  93.44305
15: 2010   120.95 113.41370
16: 2010     7.94 110.68628
17: 2010   107.52 127.30682
18: 2010     2.25 103.49036
19: 2010   120.95 123.62054
20: 2010    96.38  68.57532
```

For this sample, the **expected output** should be:

```
   year   V2
1: 2010 0.45
```

Comment: That opening paragraph belongs in a comment, not the question...that's where I'd put it, anyway. It's what the folks on [meta] call "noise"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
wages[, list(foo= sum(tentgelt > te_med)/.N), by = year]
#    year  foo
# 1: 2010 0.45
```

Comment: I think he said that the two don't add to 1, so you'd need to divide by `(tentgelt>te_med)/((tentgelt>te_med)+(tentgelt<te_med)` rather than `.N`

Comment: @Jason OPs code don't work. Even if it would work they won't reach desired output using it because `9/11 != 0.45`, while Yevgeny did `9/20 = 0.45` which is the desired output. Either way, in order to mimic OPs original code, one could do `wages[, .(foo = {temp <- sum(tentgelt > te_med) ; temp/(.N-temp)}), by= year]`

Comment: One follow-up: In the sample data `te_med` is not missing. If `te_med` is allowed to be `NAN`, do I have to put `na.rm=TRUE` into all 3 of the sums?

Comment: your option is correct, but if you want the `.N` answer to work you'll need to add `!is.na(te_med)` as a condition to the data.table